# Specifying the DOM parent element of an Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-out

Using Lightning Out, createComponent takes a domLocator parameter that specifies where in the DOM to insert the component. I was wondering if there is was a way to do this in Aura apps without Lightning Out, but that have standard DOM elements inside the app where I would like to specify the parent DOM element of a created component.

Comment: Looking at the Lightning Out code, it seems to be calling something called `$A.render` with parameters which include the host element., However, this entry point is undocumented as far as I can tell, and Salesforce being Salesforce they probably have this blocked in some way. I'm planning to give it a try very soon. (By the way, it also calls `$A.afterRender` which might well be mandatory.)